# WP_Query with the "offset" argument

Tags: customization, posts, php, wp-query

I'm making a custom query for posts using something like:

```
$p = new WP_Query(); 
$p->query(array('offset' => 30, 'posts_per_page' => 10));
```

If I have 36 posts on the entire blog, `$p->post_count` will return the number of posts that were retrieved, 6 in this case.

I need to get the post count just like I would if I omitted this 2 arguments (so I can calculate the remaining post count). How can I do that, without making another query?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Custom_Queries_using_Offset_and_Pagination

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The found_posts property `$p->found_posts` will return it.